# How to get digit values from String?

Tags: java, string

How to split a string?

I've got a `String`:

```
String s = "1+2*3(30+4/2-(10+2))*2+1";
```

Got method which get digit values from `String`:

```
private static DigitStack getNumber(String convert) {
        String[] arr = convert.split("");
        digitStack = new DigitStack();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
                while (arr[i].matches("\\d+")) {
                    digitStack.push(Double.valueOf(arr[i]));
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return digitStack;

    }
```

method return values:

```
1.0; 2.0; 3.0; [3.0  0.0]; 4.0; 2.0; [1.0  0.0]; 2.0; 2.0; 1.0;
```

expected output:

```
   1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 30.0; 4.0; 2.0; 10.0; 2.0; 2.0; 1.0;
```

Problem is method count every symbol like separate, and number 30 and 10. It convert in two numbers [3.0 and 0.0] [1.0 and 0.0]

How to fix it?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: You may want to rethink `convert.split("")`. Try printing `arr` contents and see how they can be improved.

Comment: They should be in that way

Comment: You can get number between two operator or symbol .

Comment: String may change and operators and symbols may change 2.

Comment: In your question, the sample string only contains positive integer numbers. Can it contain decimal numbers and negative numbers?

Comment: you have to apply filtering concept by which you can detect current character is  number  or symbols

Comment: You are splitting your String into individual characters so it is treating each digit separately.  Is the input string limit to integer values or may it include floating point values as well?  Are the operators well-defined so you can positively use them for discrimination?

Comment: If you have an array like `[3, 0] ` you can multiply each digit by the correct power of 10 and then add them up. There are 2 characters so the first digit becomes 30 for `30 + 0 = 30`. If you had `[1, 2, 5]` if would be `100 + 20 + 5 = 125`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way would be to split your string on non-digits i.e.

```
String s = "1+2*3(30+4/2-(10+2))*2+1";
String[] arr = s.split("\\D+");
```

This will return an array

```
[1, 2, 3, 30, 4, 2, 10, 2, 2, 1]
```

which you can then iterate through and convert to double.

As Rohit pointed out this approach will not work if you have numbers with decimal points or if you want to consider also negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] digits = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
            .matcher("1+2*3(30+4/2-(10+2))*2+1")
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

`\d+` in regex refers to one or more digits.

This returns the array:

```
{ "1", "2", "3", "30", "4", "2", "10", "2", "2", "1" }
```

If you want to convert this to a number array:

```
double[] matches = Arrays.stream(digits)
        .mapToDouble(Float::parseFloat)
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java 9 you can simply get all matches for the regex and convert them to double.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult; 

private static DigitStack getNumber(String convert) {
    digitStack = new DigitStack();

    try {
        String numbers[] = Pattern.compile("\\d(\\d+|\\.)+")
                      .matcher(convert)
                      .results()
                      .map(MatchResult::group)
                      .toArray(String[]::new);

        for(String number : numbers ) digitStack.push(Double.valueOf(number));

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return digitStack;

}
```

The problem with your code was that you were checking every character separately. You have to get all numbers first then convert them to double.

Answer (score 0):

This will get both integer and floating point values assuming that are syntactically correct. Operators, parens, and variables are ignored.

```
String str = "1.9+.2*3(30.2+4./2-(10.23+2))*2+1";
String[] digits = str.split("[^\\d\\.]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
```

Prints

```
[1.9, .2, 3, 30.2, 4., 2, 10.23, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little different because I'm assuming that you'll eventually want the operators as well as the values.

Here's the result from one of my test runs.

```
Original Equation:            1+2*3(30+4/2-(10+2))*2+1
Expanded Equation:            1 + 2 * 3 ( 30 + 4 / 2 - ( 10 + 2 ) ) * 2 + 1
```

It looks like all I did was add spaces to the equation.  What I actually did was divide the equation into parts, and print each part, followed by a space.

Here's the code I wrote to create a `List<String>` of parts from the original equation.

```
private List<String> parseEquation(String equation) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String testCharacters = "+-*/()";
    char[] letters = equation.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (letters[i] == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        
        if (Character.isDigit(letters[i])) {
            builder.append(letters[i]);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (letters[i] == '.') {
            builder.append(letters[i]);
            continue;
        }
        
        if (contains(letters[i], testCharacters)) {
            addPart(parts, builder);
            parts.add(Character.toString(letters[i]));
        }
    }
    
    addPart(parts, builder);
    
    return parts;
}

private void addPart(List<String> parts, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (builder.length() > 0) {
        parts.add(builder.toString());
        builder.delete(0, builder.length());
    }
}

private boolean contains(char c, String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char t = text.charAt(i);
        if (c == t) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

The `addPart` method is a utility method that checks for an empty part.  If the part is not empty, this method adds the part to the `List`.

The `contains` method is a utility method that allows me to check for all the operators and parenthesis with one `if` statement.

The `parseEquation` method doesn't use any fancy regexes.  It's straightforward.

I check each character in the equation.  If the character is a space, I skip the character.  If the character is a digit or a dot, I add it to the `StringBuilder` to create a number.  If the character is an operator or parenthesis, I add the previous number to the `List` of parts, then add the operator or parenthesis to the `List` of parts.

I use `continue` statements to skip to the bottom of the `for` loop and make the code a little neater.  I don't have nested `if` statements with the `continue` statements.

Here's the complete, runnable code.  You can see by the commented line that I wrote an equation solver as well.  I'll leave that part of the code to you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EquationSolver {
    
    private static final String FORMAT = "%-30s";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String equation = "1+2*3(30+4/2-(10+2))*2+1";
        String title = String.format(FORMAT, "Original Equation:");
        System.out.println(title + equation);
        
        EquationSolver es = new EquationSolver();
        List<String> parts = es.parseEquation(equation);
//      es.processEquation(parts);
        title = String.format(FORMAT, "Expanded Equation:");
        System.out.println(title + es.toString(parts));
    }

    private List<String> parseEquation(String equation) {
        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String testCharacters = "+-*/()";
        char[] letters = equation.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            if (letters[i] == ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            
            if (Character.isDigit(letters[i])) {
                builder.append(letters[i]);
                continue;
            }
            
            if (letters[i] == '.') {
                builder.append(letters[i]);
                continue;
            }
            
            if (contains(letters[i], testCharacters)) {
                addPart(parts, builder);
                parts.add(Character.toString(letters[i]));
            }
        }
        
        addPart(parts, builder);
        
        return parts;
    }

    private void addPart(List<String> parts, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            parts.add(builder.toString());
            builder.delete(0, builder.length());
        }
    }
    
    private boolean contains(char c, String text) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char t = text.charAt(i);
            if (c == t) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    private String toString(List<String> parts) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : parts) {
            builder.append(s).append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString().trim();
    }

}
```