# Is there a way to split() on multiple characters in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, text-parsing

I'm trying to split a user input which is in the format "(1 + 4) * (1 - 0)" by splitting the brackets and the whitespace, so I get an array of the operands and operator. I have been using the split() method but I don't know how to pass through two arguments. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could parse each character of the string and add them to an output array, if there are neither a parenthesis or a space characters.

Comment: Please post your code having used the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) with one argument as  [example]. Maybe we could improve the __regex__ to split on both, _space_ and _parentheses_

Comment: What would the 2 arguments be?

Comment: Take a look at my [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64575524/how-to-get-digit-values-from-string/64579565#64579565) for a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Split using Regular Expression

You can use a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (short: regex) - the single argument of the split method.

This regex contains a *pattern* (e.g. multiple characters) that is used to split the string. In other words you can fit all your split-characters (whitespace and brackets) into a single argument.

#### Split chars used

In your case 3 characters are used to split the formula:

- a *whitespace*, in regular expressions noted by `\s` (use backslash to differentiate from usual letter 's' )
- an opening parentheses, in regular expressions noted by `\(` (used alone it has a special meaning in regular expressions, thus it is also escaped by backslash)
- a closing parentheses, in regular expressions noted by `\)` (used alone it has a special meaning in regular expressions, thus it is also escaped by backslash)

This can be combined with a (boolean) or `|` as complete regex matching each of them: `\s\(\)`.

**Tip:** You can test this and other regular-expressions at [RegexPlanet](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydvywb6r).

#### The working function

**Note:** In Java you have to *escape* the backslash inside a string with another backslash. So the whitespace-regex would look like this inside a string: `\\s`.

```java
    public static String[] splitFormula(String formula) {
        return formula.split("\\(|\\)|\\s"); // split by opening-parenthese or closing-parentheses or whitespace
    }
```

Will return following string array `{"1", "+", "4", "*", "1", "-", "0"}`.

Run [this demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/mGMsqs).

Answer (score 0):

Split method takes a regex pattern

You'd pass multiple characters with a character class like `"[\\s()]"` for spaces and brackets, however, you then lose the brackets, so your order of operations would be unknown

Comment: order of precedenc don't matter i got that sorted, but thanks

Comment: what does the s do?

Comment: \s means a Whitespace character

Comment: If you had something like `2 + (4-5) / (6+(7*3) / 5)`,i think splitting on parentheses would be problematic